# Connecting to bluetooth module using Flutter bluetooth serial package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I am developing an app that writes a '1' to a Bluetooth(HC-05 so I cant use BLE) module whenever I press the button,

I looked over Bluetooth serial's example code and I cant seem to find proper documentations to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.